# Gerar um novo array a partir de outro com reduce javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Tenho o seguinte array:

```
const array = [
  { a: 1, b: 2 },
  { a: 1, b: 1 },
  { a: 3, b: 4 }
];
```

Gostaria que um segundo array fosse gerado, para cada vez em que repetisse o atributo **a**, gere um novo elemento onde o **a** mantém seu valor, e o **b** some com o **b** do segundo índice do array, tendo como resultado esse array abaixo:

```
[
  { a: 1, b: 3 },
  { a: 3, b: 4 }
];
```

Para isso, usei o *reduce* do *javascript*, da seguinte forma:

```
const array = [
  { a: 1, b: 2 },
  { a: 1, b: 1 },
  { a: 3, b: 4 }
];

const result = [];

array.reduce((acc, cur)=>{
  let response = {};
  if(acc.a === cur.a){
    response.a = cur.a;
    response.b = acc.b + cur.b;
  }else{
    response = cur;

  }
  result.push(response);
  return cur;
},0);

console.log(result)
```

Tendo como resultado:

```
[ { a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 2, b: 3 }, { a: 3, b: 4 } ]
```

Como faço para que meu resultado seja :

```
[ { a: 2, b: 3 }, { a: 3, b: 4 } ]
```

Usando Javascript e reduce;

> OBS: o array demonstrado no exemplo acima, é somente de exemplo, o
>   original é bem extenso e também dinâmico. Portanto, usei o reduce para
>   acessar os itens corridos e os anteriores de cada índice desse array.

Comment: Mas o qual o resultado pretendido? É `[  { a: 1, b: 3 },  { a: 3, b: 4 } ]` ou `[ { a: 2, b: 3 }, { a: 3, b: 4 } ]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não precisa usar o método [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) para obter o que quer. Na verdade não é o método mais adequado para gerar um conjunto de objetos, em sua documentação `reduce()` está definido assim:

> O método `reduce()` executa uma função redutora, fornecida por você, para
> cada elemento do array, resultando num **único** valor de retorno.

Ou seja você está desviando a finalidade de uso do método `reduce()` pois você não está tentando reduzir os elementos da entrada a um único objeto e sim a vários.

A não ser que seja um desafio para ver quem faz a maior gambiarra para somar um determinado campo de vários objetos tendo como referência outro campo desses objetos, é suficiente apenas iterar pelo array com [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), ou usar um simples [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) como lembrou [HKotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo), e ir somando os respectivos valores de `b` com os valores já armazenados em um array resultado onde o índice seja `a`. Segue o exemplo comentado:

```js
//Array de testes
let arr =[{ a: 1, b: 2 },{ a: 1, b: 5 },{ a: 1, b: 1 },{ a: 1, b: 1 },{ a: 11, b: 11 },{ a: 3, b: 4 },{ a: 3, b: 4 },{ a: 3, b: 4 },{ a: 3, b: 4 },{ a: 3, b: 4 },{ a: 3, b: 41 },{ a: 13, b: 41 }];

//Array que receberá o resultado
let result = [];

//Para todos os elementos de arr
arr.forEach(item =>{
  //Se result não tiver o índice item.a definido inicializa result[item.a]
  if (result[item.a] == undefined) result[item.a] = {"a":item.a, "b":0};
  //Soma item.b ao seu respectivo elemento em result
  result[item.a].b += item.b;
});
//Remove os indices não utilizados de result
result = result.filter(item => !!item);
console.log(result);
```

O mesmo exemplo acima usando um laço de iteração [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of):

```js
//Array de testes
let arr =[{ a: 1, b: 2 },{ a: 1, b: 5 },{ a: 1, b: 1 },{ a: 1, b: 1 },{ a: 11, b: 11 },{ a: 3, b: 4 },{ a: 3, b: 4 },{ a: 3, b: 4 },{ a: 3, b: 4 },{ a: 3, b: 4 },{ a: 3, b: 41 },{ a: 13, b: 41 }];

//Array que receberá o resultado
let result = [];

//Para todos os elementos de arr
for(let item of arr){
  //Se result não tiver o índice item.a definido inicializa result[item.a]
  if (result[item.a] == undefined) result[item.a] = {"a":item.a, "b":0};
  //Soma item.b ao seu respectivo elemento em result
  result[item.a].b += item.b;
};
//Remove os indices não utilizados de result
result = result.filter(item => !!item);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Perfeito! As outras respostas estão usando `reduce` para percorrer o array, o que é um uso torto do mesmo, já que um `forEach` (ou um `for` simples) seria o suficiente. +1

Answer (score -1):

Consegui da seguinte maneira.

Array de exemplo :

```
[
  { a: 1, b: 2 },
  { a: 1, b: 5 },
  { a: 1, b: 1 },
  { a: 1, b: 1 },
  { a: 11, b: 11 },
  { a: 3, b: 4 },
  { a: 3, b: 4 },
  { a: 3, b: 4 },
  { a: 3, b: 4 }, 
  { a: 3, b: 4 }, 
  { a: 3, b: 41 },
  { a: 13, b: 41 },
];
```

Array esperado como resultado:

```
[
  { a: 1, b: 9 },
  { a: 11, b: 11 },
  { a: 3, b: 61 },
  { a: 13, b: 41 }
];
```

```js
   const array = [
  { a: 1, b: 2 },
  { a: 1, b: 5 },
  { a: 1, b: 1 },
  { a: 1, b: 1 },
  { a: 11, b: 11 },
  { a: 3, b: 4 },
  { a: 3, b: 4 },
  { a: 3, b: 4 },
  { a: 3, b: 4 }, 
  { a: 3, b: 4 }, 
  { a: 3, b: 41 },
  { a: 13, b: 41 },
];


const result = [];
const allIndex = [];

array.reduce((acc, cur,index)=>{
  //Verifico se o indice atual é igual ao anterior
  if(cur.a === acc.a ){
const response = {};
response.a = cur.a;
response.b = acc.b + cur.b; 
//Caso sim, o atributo b recebe a soma dos valores b passado.
result.push(response)
return response;
  }else{
//caso não, eu verifico se o indice atual é menor que o tamanho atual do novo array sendo criado
if(index < array.length) allIndex.push(result.length - 1);
result.push(cur)
return cur;
  }
  
});



allIndex.push(result.length - 1);

console.log('RESULTADO');
result.map((element,index) => {
  if(allIndex.includes(index)){
console.log(element);
  }
})
```

Tendo então o console.log mostrando todos os elementos do novo array, assim posso adicionar em um novo array para uso futuro.